# how to avoid the ok button of the alarm

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

Im using alarm intent to set an alarm

Code :

```
Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM); 
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, meet); 
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hour); 
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, min); 
startActivity(i);
```

As i have already selected the time ,date and the message from my app i don't want to make any changes So in the alarm app as this intent is fired.

I have to press the OK button every time i set an alarm.
[image: Screenshot]

I don't want this screen to popup, and press the `Ok` button again and again. what should I do?

Is there a way to send OK request in the intent itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have to press the OK button every time i set an alarm.

The behavior will vary by alarm clock application.

> i don't want this screen to popup, and press the Ok button again and again. what should i do

Write your own alarm clock application, or find one that does not prompt you to press OK.

> Is there a way to send OK request in the intent itself?

No.

Comment: if im using the android alarm to set the alarm even then there is no option?

Comment: intents are handled by the remote app, if the alarm offers no way to handle it there is no way to do it.

Comment: @user2425426: "if im using the android alarm to set the alarm even then there is no option?" -- there is no "android alarm". Different devices will ship with different applications that respond to your requested `Intent`. Even on "Google experience" devices, the behavior varies by OS level.

Comment: thank you !! i had a doubt,and thought if its possible, now i surely know its not :)

Answer (score 1):

You can right your own alarm service class..  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html